# C# function overloading not throwing compilation error

Tags: c#, .net, polymorphism

I have a question on function overloading, Can you please let me know why it is not showing compilation error

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var inputObj = new CalcClass();
        Console.WriteLine(inputObj.AddNumber(null, null));
    }
}
class CalcClass
{
    public double AddNumber(double? a, double? b)
    {
        return (double)(a ?? 0 + b ?? 0);
    }
    public short AddNumber(short? a, short? b)
    {
        return (short)(a ?? 0 + b ?? 0);
    }
    public int AddNumber(int? a, int? b)
    {
        return (int)(a ?? 0 + b ?? 0);
    }
}
```

It is executing the `public short AddNumber(short? a, short? b)` function even though ambiguous between the class methods

Comment: That's overloading, not polymorphism.

Comment: I have update description now

Comment: What makes you think it *is* ambiguous?

Comment: "Given two different types T1 and T2, T1 is a better conversion target than T2 if at least one of the following holds:
... An implicit conversion from T1 to T2 exists, and no implicit conversion from T2 to T1 exists"

Comment: Read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/overload-resolution). It has a nice flow chart on "How to pick your Overload?"  With an exemple of byte short and int. Thats is really close to your test

Comment: @DragandDrop That's not even the same language.

Comment: @itsme86, And? You think the process is different?

Comment: @DragandDrop Why would you assume they're the same? If I'm going to change the spark plugs in my Ford, I'm not going to go to a Chevy manual for the gap information.

Comment: @DragandDrop - they do have different overloading and shadowing rules. Not relevant to this specific example but reasoning about one language by trying to use the other language's rules won't always work.

Comment: @Fildor: try this
Console.WriteLine((new CalcClass()).Print(null));
public string Print(IEnumerable<string> names)
        {
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (var item in names)
                sb.Append(item + ", ");
            return sb.ToString();
        }
        public string Print(string names)
        {
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (var item in names.Split(';'))
            {
                sb.Append(item + ", ");
            }
            return sb.ToString();
        }

Comment: @itsme86
When it  comes to Picking an overload things can change depending of the version. I'm pretty you have read the specification. So you are aware of the complexity of the subject. The main goal of my comment was to provide a visual help to "how to pick an Overload". If you spot any difference between this article and ?? And what by the way as every major version can have different spec.. I remember the difference between c#4 and c#6  was about type inference and lambda.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, this is why this is a comment and not an answer. Because the exact way to pick an overload is complex rules about lambda, anonymous method is not trivial.

Comment: @Santosh_Sams _That_ example has nothing to do with the one in the question. Those are two reference types.

Comment: If we decide to be picky about this "simple vb" implementation. We have to decide to witch C# version and Framework we want to explain the spec. But op is not talking about something really specific that will require the spec.